# CSS animation make reverse animaton speed slower

Tags: css, css-animations

1. How to make on mouse leaving first div animation play backwards text gets smaller gradually not instantly?
2. How to make backwards play speed 5 times slower?

Here is a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1p30w1v0/) of the below:

```css
.two {
  font-size: 0;
}
.one:hover + .two {
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-animation: zoom_in 0.5s ease 0s forwards;
  -moz-animation: zoom_in 0.5s ease 0s forwards;
  -o-animation: zoom_in 0.5s ease 0s forwards;
}
@-webkit-keyframes zoom_in {
  from {
    font-size: 0;
  }
  to {
    font-size: 20px;
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes zoom_in {
  from {
    font-size: 0;
  }
  to {
    font-size: 20px;
  }
}
@-o-keyframes zoom_in {
  from {
    font-size: 0;
  }
  to {
    font-size: 20px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="one">
  Hover
</div>
<div class="two">
  Hello World!
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your example, only the `:hover` pseudo class has the animation. When the cursor leaves the first div, the hover state is instantly left and there is no animation specified. The animation needs to also be set on the `.two` class.

---

That said, for a hover effect like this, CSS keyframe animation may be unnecessary. We can use a simple [`transition`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition).

The `:hover` pseudo class is given a faster transition duration, and the div class is given a slower transition duration. The `:hover` state is left when the cursor leaves the div and the slower transition on the div takes over.

### Example

```css
.two {
  font-size: 0;
}
.two {
  text-align: center;
  transition: font-size 2.5s; /* slower out */
}
.one:hover + .two {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  transition: font-size 0.5s; /* faster in */
}
```

```html
<div class="one">
  Hover
</div>
<div class="two">
  Hello World!
</div>
```